# Replacing HTML tags with text attributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, html-parsing

I'm getting data from a web service and the result contains some HTML tags, that I'm then trying to convert. For example, I want to replace `<P>` tags with line breaks, and `<STRONG>` from HTML to bold text.

Can anyone help me? I've sort of worked out how I can replace text -- I'm halfway there, I think.

```
 if([key isEqualToString:@"Description"]){
            txtDesc.text=[results objectForKey:key];
            NSString * a = txtDesc.text;

            NSString * b = [a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<strong>" withString:@"STRONG TAG"];
            b =  [b stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<\\/p>" withString:@""];
            b =  [b stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@""];

            txtDesc.text=b;

        }
```

Comment: The answer says to use a webview but I don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before you need to use NSAttributedString

It implements the following method which you will pass an NSDictionary of attributes and a range (of characteres) to receive the attributes

```
- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes range:(NSRange)range;
```

An example of NSDictionary would be:

```
@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSyze:24], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]}
```

You can look for more information on apple's documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

or on the Lecture 4 of the **amazing** iPhone Application Development course from Stanford
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2013-winter

Comment: Thanks this is exactly something I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 4):

Strings do not have attributes like bold. Strings contain only chars including line breaker. If you want to enrich your string with attributes, have a look at NSAttributedString.

Update:
For those of us, who cannot see, why attributed strings are the solution, a simple piece of code:

```
- (NSAttributedString*)attributedStringByReplaceHtmlTag:(NSString*)tagName withAttributes:(NSDictionary*)attributes
{
    NSString *openTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", tagName];
    NSString *closeTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>", tagName];
    NSMutableAttributedString *resultingText = [self mutableCopy];
    while ( YES )   {
        NSString *plainString = [resultingText string];
        NSRange openTagRange = [plainString rangeOfString:openTag];
        if (openTagRange.length==0) {
            break;
        }

        NSRange searchRange;
        searchRange.location = openTagRange.location+openTagRange.length;
        searchRange.length = [plainString length]-searchRange.location;
        NSRange closeTagRange = [plainString rangeOfString:closeTag options:0 range:searchRange];

        NSRange effectedRange;
        effectedRange.location = openTagRange.location+openTagRange.length;
        effectedRange.length = closeTagRange.location - effectedRange.location;

        [resultingText setAttributes:attributes range:effectedRange];
        [resultingText deleteCharactersInRange:closeTagRange];
        [resultingText deleteCharactersInRange:openTagRange];

    }

    return resultingText;
}
```

But I did not test it well, because I had to prepare a risotto while programming that. ;-)

Comment: He has to parse the tags out of the html string and set correspondending attributes to the instance of NSAttributedString. The relevant part of my answer is: "You cannot do this with NSString."

Comment: I found this very helpful as I didn't want to implement a complete HTML Parser that's time consuming and works in various different ways. This did exactly what I was after which was transform a specific wrapped word/s into attributed versions. Appreciate it!

Comment: really good this one!